# Merging two strings to one String without duplicate alphabets in ascending alphabetical order

Tags: java, string, sorting, merge

Suppose I have 2 strings:

- str1 = "bcdefghijkl"
- str2 = "ehikoz"

I want to copy the elements of `str2` into `str1` such that the resulting `str1` = `"bcdefghikoz"`.

For example,

- str1 = "aefghlowxyz", str2 = "delo", result = "adefghlowxy"
- str1 = "befghklnqtz", str2 = "cehix", result = "bcefghiklnx"

A few conditions are:
 - The elements should remain in alphabetical order
 - The size of string a should remain 11
 - If an alphabet of `str2` is not in `str1` already then it should replace the elements of `str1` in alphabetical order

Comment: The title of your question is totally different from what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying elements of one string into another of fixed size in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896750/copying-elements-of-one-string-into-another-of-fixed-size-in-java)

Comment: Please don't post duplicates. Make an effort to improve the original post or delete it and improve this one.

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa i mean to say merging 2 strings

Comment: Is more than that... you are reordering the inserted chars alphabetical

Comment: @Pillar - Please don't post links to pages that do not exist or that have been deleted. It will simply confuse the OP.

Comment: @DevilsHnd It was just deleted, it was their own post.

Answer (score -1):

1) Iterate through each string character in variable **b** and remove that character from the string held in variable **a** (if it's there) using the **string.replace()** method;

2) Append the string held in variable **a** to the string held in variable **b**;

3) Trim off excess characters from the string held in variable **b** (ie: **b = b.substring(0, 11)**;

4) Sort the characters in variable **b** (ie: using the **String.toCharArray()** and **java.util.Arrays.sort()** methods;

You're Done.

The next time you post a question be sure to provide the code you have tried.

Comment: This algorithm will not produce the results requested:
•a="befghklnqtz" , b="cehix" result= "bcefghiklnz"   For the OP: why does the desired result contain a "z" and not contain a "x"?

Comment: @FredK is right (thank you for spotting that Fred) I was a little backwards there and have made the correction. And that's a good point...If following the rules (all characters in b to be in a, sorted ascending, and 11 character max) there should be no "z" within the result what so ever. What's up with that? The result should be:  "bcefghiklnx"

Comment: Obviously the results shown in the OP's examples above are flawed since the first example shows a result of 12 characters instead of 11 as his/her own rules have dictated. Either that or the character limit should be that of the string length in variable 'a'. The OP needs to specify.